# Booting Windows VM in server asks for OS CD

Tags: windows, kvm-virtualization

Using KVM I have installed Windows Virtual machine in Ubuntu server 11.04. Every time if I boot the Windows VM, it asks for OS CD. But other Linux VMs boot properly.

I need Windows VM to be booted properly like other linux VMs. Can any one help?

Comment: Since you replied to your own question with a fix, you should select an answer as the right one, so people can see that this question was solved, and see which answer was the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the Particular Windows VM and select "View" from toolbar. From there select "IDE CDROM1", click on the "disconnect" option to disconnect the media(CD). After that it does not asks for CD.

Windows Vm -> View -> IDE CDROM1 -> Disconnect

Answer (score 0):

Check if the CD device is still "attached" to that VM.  If you had the CD "attached" to the vm when you installed it... make sure you "detach" the cd from the VM.